# How do I add multiple values in EnumMember attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, serialization

How do I add multiple values in EnumMember attribute ?

```
[JsonProperty("type")]
        public AssetType Type { get; set; }  

[JsonConverter(typeof(EnumConverter))]
       public enum AssetType
            {
                [EnumMember(Value = "node")]
                Folder
        }
```

I need something like

```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(EnumConverter))]
           public enum AssetType
                {
                    [EnumMember(Value = "node","collection")]
                    Folder
            }
```

Meaning the value that came from json if is node or collection I need to convert to folder AssetType

Comment: Could you use an enum where multiple members have the same value? `[EnumMember("node")] Folder, [EnumMember("collection")] Collection = Folder,`

Comment: Has this question been solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do as canton7 suggests and assign Folder to multiple members like so

```
enum AssetType
{
    Folder,
    [EnumMember(Value = "node")]
    Node = Folder,
    [EnumMember(Value = "collection")]
    Collection = Folder
}
```

(and yes, `AssertType.Node == AssertType.Folder`)

Or if that is not possible in your case use [your own JsonConverter](https://bytefish.de/blog/enums_json_net/#using-a-custom-jsonconverter) to write the parsing method yourself.